# What is a good coding style for setting and changing application level constants?

Tags: programming

Background: Every application has user-definable constants. The Java language has the Properties class to handle them.

Question: What is a good and re-usable coding style for setting and changing application level constants in Mathematica?

Comment: Would you describe in further detail what you need?  I am not familiar with `Java` so your analogy does not help me.

Comment: Think of values like directories, authorization, connection strings for a database, ip addresses, logging level etc. Things that are relatively constant for several apps, but may need to be changed in an easy way. - It's easy to do but I would like to know how you guys do it and what standards you use, in Java for example it is common to name constants in ALLUPPERCASE.

Comment: What kind of interface does your application have?  Notebook?  Java?

Comment: Since it seems like you want constants accessible from a number of applications, why not create a package of constants and start each application by calling the constants you need.  You would then change the constants only in the package should they ever need changing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - The user-interface is ( currently ) Notebook, and Java is used for custom language parsing ( ANTLR ).

Comment: @Jagra then show me some examples on how you do it, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it seems like you want constants accessible from a number of applications, why not create a package of constants and start each application by calling the constants you need. You would then change the constants only in the package should they ever need changing.

```
    (* Mathematica Package *)

    BeginPackage["CONSTANTS`"]
    (* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *)  

    constant1::usage = "some text"
    constant2::usage = "some text"
    constant3::usage = "some text"

    Begin["`Private`"] (* Begin Private Context *) 

    constant1[]: = 22;
    constant2[]: = "myConstant";
    constant3[]: = 0.618;

    End[] (* End Private Context *)

    EndPackage[]
```

See: [Package development](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PackageDevelopment.html)
Place package in an appropriate directory so Mathematica can see it.

To give your notebooks access to the constants:

```
Needs["CONSTANTS`"]

constant1[]
constant2[]
constant3[]

22
"myConstant"
0.618
```

Just a sketch but this should give you the idea.

Comment: Mathematically elegant. "For constants define a function that returns a constant."

Comment: Thank for noticing ;-)  It did occur to me that Mathematica looks at everything as an expression.  Some OOP languages also see variables and constants as objects.